# Struts 2 application throws 404 exception

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

In my struts 2.3.16.1 application, after filter mapping in the web.xml "resource not found exception" occurs .Even the jsp pages in web directory also shows the same exception.
Thanks for your help in advance.

```
       <filter>
            <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
            <filter-class>
                    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
            </filter-class>
    </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
```

struts.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
       "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

    <struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="getTutorial" class="org.kishore.struts2.TutorialAction">
    <result>/success.jsp</result>
    </action>

    </package>

    </struts>
```

Comment: A request to which resource/page is returning 404?

Comment: when i try to access getTutorial.action.

Comment: I  think it is running for `<result name="input">` provide jsp page path for that

Answer (score 0):

If your error is

> type Status report
>
> message /YourProjectName/success.jsp
>
> description The requested resource is not available.

Then it means your `success.jsp` page is missing

And if message is blank and in console error is

> Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/C:/Users/Parth/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/serializ/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:7:75

then your class `org.kishore.struts2.TutorialAction.java` is missing

If you are getting following error

> SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/F:/apache-tomcat-6.0.39/wtpwebapps/struts2starter/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-‌​portlet-plugin-2.3.16.1.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:31:133 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(Configurati‌​onManager.java:70)
>
> **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.portlet.PortletMode**

It means download [Portlet Api 2.0.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/portlet/portlet-api/2.0/portlet-api-2.0.jar) because without it you will not be able to use `struts2-‌​portlet-plugin-2.3.16.1.jar`. If you do not add `Portlet Api 2.0.jar`  you will continue getting error **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.portlet.PortletMode**

**Note:** Also make sure you are using compatible version of jars which have same version as `struts-core-2.x.x.jar.`

**For example** if you are using `struts2-core-2.2.3.jar` then you must use `struts2-‌​portlet-plugin-2.2,3.jar`.

Comment: i am getting the following error in the console SEVERE: Dispatcher     initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/F:/apache-tomcat-6.0.39/wtpwebapps/struts2starter/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-portlet-plugin-2.3.16.1.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:31:133
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)

Comment: I updated answer. please see it. And also let me know if any more error is coming.If you are new to stackoverflow see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?lq=1

Comment: I am using struts2-‌​portlet-plugin-2.3.16.1.jar and struts-core-2.3.16.1.jar i.e both are same version.Still i am getting the error

Comment: I added in answer  **Note:** Also download `Portlet Api 2.0.jar` because without it you will not be able to use `struts2-‌​portlet-plugin-2.3.16.1.jar`.